# Chnage url using .htaccess in Php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to change my url --> localhost/mysitename/get_file.php

to

localhost/mysitename/file2

using .htaccess ..Any suggestions.?

Comment: You must use .htaccess if you had APACHE mod_rewrite activated like this : RewriteRule ^file2$ get_file.php [L]

Comment: Do you want make a redirect? or do you want when you write http://localhost/mysitename/file2 in the browser localhost/mysitename/get_file.php will be executed?

Comment: RewriteCond / RewriteRule using %{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: Yes..M using .htaccess ..but in the most of other answers there is a directory before the file name..So I need rewrite rule..@mathieu

Comment: I want this -> localhost/mysitename/file2 when I type this-> localhost/mysitename/get_file.php using .htaccess rewrite rule.. @Curlas

Comment: For path translation:
RewriteRule ^/mysitename/file2$ /mysitename/get_file.php [NC,PT,L]

Comment: For 301 redirect:
RewriteRule ^/mysitename/get_file.php$ /mysitename/file2 [R=301,L]

Comment: Hi.. @Curlas ..Its not working.. I need to translate the path...I used this -> RewriteRule ^/mysitename/file2$ /mysitename/get_file.php [NC,PT,L]

Comment: Try to use my first source code ! You must type http://localhost/mysitename/file2 from the URL...

Comment: No.. @MathieuDormeval ..Its also nt working . ..And I need this -> localhost/mysitename/file2  when I type this-> localhost/mysitename/get_file.php

Comment: Were have you placed the htaccess file ?

Comment: inside "mysitename" folder...

Comment: Take it on the root folder or create an APACHE vhost !

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to create an .htaccess file

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

this is the content of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\file2$ /mysitename/get_file.php [L]
```

Comment: reason for -1 ?

Comment: This is nt what I am looking for.. there is jst a minor error in htaccess and the site you suggested is not working for me..Though .. @gianluca

Comment: so basically people want the fish instead of the fishing rod, good to know :-)

Comment: Yeah..can say so.. As m in hurry and I tried ..bt dint get what I want.. It redirects the page.. and I need to translate the path only.. @gianluca

Comment: my car is not working, please fix it! :-) (subtle hint to ask you for more details)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128371/discussion-between-dhruvi-mistry-and-gianluca-ghettini).